# Does php-memcached have any local caching buffer?

Tags: php, memcached

Our lead developer claims that memcached owns some local caching buffer.
So he is doing some actions in code, that would lead to hundreds-thousands of calls to memcached with almost everytime the same keys.
It would definetly lead to many memory allocations, but would it require network overhead?

I did try to read the source code of php-memcached, but it just calls libmemcached's function (I don't remember its name) and I couldn't figure out where can I find its definition.

Comment: So the question is, if you do multiple actions using the same key, is memcached allocating/deallocating memory at the target machine or is it just doing those in the "local buffer"?

Comment: You mean it keeps a local buffer on the client side? If that were the case it would definitely reduce network overhead.

Comment: @N.B. , Jack, Yes, I meant local caching

Comment: Does anyone know how can I find definition of memcached_mget_by_key function? Google points me to memcached manual, and I can't find it here https://code.launchpad.net/libmemcached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How exactly your lead developer managed to extract that information would have been useful. From the [list of constants](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php), this particular option sticks out:

```
Memcached::OPT_BUFFER_WRITES
```

It's used to buffer writes to Memcached to reduce network overheads; however, it also states that a read operation immediately *flushes* that buffer to the server.

Web searches so far didn't provide any information to either substantiate or contradict the statement, though if there was such a feature there should be an option to switch off that behaviour; the absence of which leads me to believe that it's not there.